# Removing Partitioned rows from oracle sql query output

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have below query

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY COLUMN1,  COLUMN2, COLUMN3 ORDER BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2) AS ROW_NUM, COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
FROM (SUBQUERY)
GROUP BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
```

> OUTPUT of above query:-

[image: ![enter image description here]

I need to perform something equivalent to

```
IF (COLUMN2 == 'PQR' AND COLUMN3 IS NOT NULL)
THEN 
"Delete whole partition from output having value A3 in column1"
```

Explaination:-

If COLUMN2 is having value `PQR` and COLUMN3 is having any `DATE_TIME` (i.e. NOT NULL) then all the corresponding COLUMN1 value should not be present in output of query.

> OUTPUT required is:-

[image]

I tried to be as clear as I can be. Let me know if I need to clarify my question more.

> NOTE:- I want to remove those rows only from output of the query not from actual table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this using a subquery, then you might want to use window functions:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY COLUMN1,  COLUMN2, COLUMN3 ORDER BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2) AS ROW_NUM,
             COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3,
             COUNT(CASE WHEN COLUMN2 = 'PQR' THEN COLUMN3 END) OVER (PARTITION BY COLUMN1) as cnt
      FROM (SUBQUERY)
      GROUP BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
     ) s
WHERE cnt = 0;
```

This counts the number of `COLUMN3` values where `COLUMN2 = 'PQR'` over all each `COLUMN1`.  It then returns only the rows where this count is `0`.

The advantage of this approach is that it only evaluates the subquery once -- that can be a performance win (over `NOT EXISTS`) if it is complicated.

Comment: Can you please explain what this code is actually doing? So that I can make changes in my query? What I am not able to understand is how `CASE WHEN COLUMN2 = 'PQR' THEN COLUMN3` is checking for `COLUMN3 == NOT NULL`. And I am getting error `Invalid identifier cnt`. So what is the significance of `cnt=0` in the query?

Comment: @acroniks . . . The `COUNT()` counts non-`NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `select query` then you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM YOUR_TABLE T2
WHERE T1.COLUMN1 = T2.COLUMN1
AND T2.COLUMN2 = 'PQR' AND T2.COLUMN3 IS NOT NULL);
```

You can use the `EXISTS` to `delete` such records as follows:

```
DELETE FROM YOUR_TABLE T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM YOUR_TABLE T2
WHERE T1.COLUMN1 = T2.COLUMN1
AND T2.COLUMN2 = 'PQR' AND T2.COLUMN3 IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: I have one question here. Using `DELETE` will delete from output of the query or from actual table also??

Comment: @acroniks . . . `delete` deletes rows from your table and does not appear to be what you want.

Comment: Also I am using multiple sub queries from which I am filtering out the desired values of `COLUMN1`, `COLUMN2` and `COLUMN3`. So in order to use this approach I might need to assign an alias to my subqueries and the use `EXISTS` using these alias. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: You can use your query in CTE and use that CTE as YOUR_TABLE